# CS50 pset3 Music segmentation fault

Tags: c, cs50

Today I finished the music project, or at least I think I've finished it. 
On helper.c when I run make it makes both notes and synthesizer files and with no errors. But when I want to run ./notes it gives me segmentation fault error. Even when I ran the program with check50 it gave me this error:

> failed to execute program due to segmentation fault

I personally think it might be because of turning string to int or the way I got the notes from the string. First I introduced one string for taking the note and one int for taking the ovtav of the note.

The string note is something like D4 or C#4

So I will just copy this part, to check with you if I've done it correctly.

```
string noteletter="";
int noteoctav;
if (strlen(note) == 3)
{
    noteletter[0] = note[0];
    noteletter[1] = note[1];
    noteoctav = note[2] - '0';
}
if (strlen(note)== 2)
{
    noteletter[0] = note[0];
    noteoctav = note[1] - '0';
}
```

### Update

Here I've added the full code so you can see what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight I've added my full code

Comment: You're not expected to show everything you've written (see the "minimal" section of [mcve]).  That said, you're still missing a `main()` and at least one `#include` line before we can reproduce what you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*

My problem was that I defined noteletter as string. I changed that part to

```
char noteletter[4];
int noteoctav;
if (strlen(note) == 3)
{
    noteletter[0] = note[0];
    noteletter[1] = note[1];
    noteletter[2] = '\0';
    noteoctav = note[2] - '0';
}
if (strlen(note)== 2)
{
    noteletter[0] = note[0];
    noteletter[1] = '\0';
    noteoctav = note[1] - '0';
}
```

and now it works :)

Answer (score 3):

Two problems I can see (assuming `string` is a typedef of `char*`)

if `noteletter` has a length of 0 (value `= ""`) then what do you think `noteletter[1]` is doing?

Even if `noteletter` was set to something bigger (e.g. `noteletter = "ABC";`) - writing to a literal string is undefined behavior.

Try `char noteletter[3] = { 0 };` to get something that (at a quick glance) looks big enough.

Another possible issue: if `note` is `NULL` or invalid then `strlen(note)` is not safe.

Comment: I've added all the code so you could see what i was trying to do. now that you said for noteletter[1], i think i should write something like   noteletter.append(note[1])    what do you think? now that you can see all the code do you think i can solve it? I would be grateful if you could help :)